# Convert [Char] to own type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In one module I have this type:

```
module Verbally (verbally, Currency) where
import Data.String.Utils

    data Currency = Currency {
    singular :: String,
    plural :: String
} deriving (Read, Show)

aud = Currency "Australian Dollar" "Australian Dollars"
bgn = Currency "Lev" "Levs"
```

In my second (main) module which looks like this:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ verbally (args !! 0) (args !! 1)
```

I want to convert args !! 1 to Currency.

Verbally takes Integer and Currency as arguments.

Compilation error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Currency’
Expected type: [Currency]
  Actual type: [String]
In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘args’
In the second argument of ‘verbally’, namely ‘(args !! 1)’
```

Comment: `Currency` has a `Read` instance, so how about using `read (args !! 1)`

Comment: For future searches, it can be helpful to use the term 'parse'.  What you are saying is that you want to parse the string and there are many ways to do that, the most simple method being `read` and `Text.Read.readMaybe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about what `verbally` requires, but I'm guessing you want this:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ verbally $ Currency (args !! 0) (args !! 1)
```